# Angular - click function on controller

Tags: angularjs

Sorry in advance but this question might be a little vague and I don't have much of a n example.

I need a sort of switch click on an element to hide and show another element.

I'm ding it like this.

```
    <div ng-click="showTask = !showTask">
        Show Task
    </div>

    <div ng-if="showTask">
        TASK
    </div>
```

My problem is I'd like to move this to the controller and not have the logic in the html

So it would look like this

```
    <div ng-click="theCtrl.showContainer()">
        Show Task
    </div>

    <div ng-if="someTask">
        TASK
    </div>
```

My problem is the code on the controller

```
    private showContainer(showContact){
        this.showTask = !this.showTask;
    }
```

I'm using Angular 1 but with Typescript.

The stripped down controller looks like this

```
    (()=>{


        class theController{


            private showContact:boolean;


            constructor(){

            }


            private showContainer(showContact){
                this.showContact = !this.showContact;
            }
        }

        angular.module('myApp').controller('theController', theController);
    })();
```

Comment: are you using `controller_as` syntax?

Comment: paste your full controller

Comment: Yes I'm using controller as

Comment: `private this.showContainer(showContact){
                this.showContact = !this.showContact;
            }`

Comment: try adding `this` to method name.

Comment: Sravan - this is what I have, and doesn't work.

Comment: added this to `showContainer?`

Comment: If I add `this.showContainer` I get an error.

Comment: okay, but I never tried `typescript` with `angular1`

Comment: but, let me search for a solution some where.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a scope function in your controller:

```
$scope.showContainer = function(){
    $scope.someTask = !$scope.someTask;
}
```

And call it in html:

```
<div ng-click="showContainer()"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Plese check below example, You can create function which can be called from the angularjs view like below.

```
 <div ng-click="theCtrl.showContainer()">
    Show Task
</div>

<div ng-if="someTask">
    TASK
</div>
```

and in your controller you have to declare your function like below

```
 this.showContainer = function(showContact){
    this.showTask = !this.showTask;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="myController as theCtrl">
   <div ng-click="theCtrl.showContainer()">
        Show Task
    </div>

    <div ng-if="theCtrl.someTask">
        TASK
    </div>
</div>
```

Your controller may be something like,

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.showContainer(){
                vm.showTask = !vm.showTask;
        }
    }])
```